# a problem with the proof that if a function has a derivative it is continuous

Tags: calculus

I have seen the proof done so:

$$\lim_{(x-c)\to 0} (f(x)-f(c))$$
$$=\lim_{(x-c)\to 0} [(x-c)\frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}]$$
$$=\lim_{(x-c)\to 0} (x-c)\lim_{(x-c)\to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$$$$=0\cdot f'(x)=0$$
my problem with this is that according to this, we can prove that any function approaches zero when x approaches zero:
$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=$$
$$\lim_{x\to 0}x\frac{f(x)}x$$
then we say that as x approaches zero so to does the value of x and therefore:$$ \lim_{x\to 0}x\frac{f(x)}x=0$$
so: $$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$$
which is obviously not true for every function.(?!)

Comment: $\lim x\frac{f(x)}{x}=\lim x\lim\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is only true if both limits exist in the first place, which would be guaranteed if $f$ were differentiable at $0$. Without this condition, you can't factorize the limit like that.

Comment: Your assertion that $\lim x\frac{f(x)}x=0$ is not justified. "x approaches zero so to does the value of x and therefore..." is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to 0} x\cdot \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x)}{x}=0$$
is true only whenever $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is bounded in a neighborhood of $0$, which is true only if $f(0)=0$.

**Method 1**

If $f$ is derivable at $a\in\mathbb R$, then $$f(a+h)=f(a)+f'(a)h+o(h),$$ and thus $$\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)=f(a),$$
i.e. it's continuous at $a$.

**Method 2**

\begin{align*}
\left|f(a+h)-f(a)\right|&=\left|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}h\right|\\
&\leq \underbrace{\left|\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}\right|}_{\to f'(a)}|h|\underset{h\to 0}{\longrightarrow }0.
\end{align*}

Therefore, $$\lim_{h\to 0}f(a+h)=f(a).$$

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are mixing something up. They were able to make the conclusion that the product goes to zero because the other limit exist which is f'.

Generally if you have a sequence (xn) goes to zero and another sequence (yn). The product sequence will go to zero iff (yn)  is bounded. In this case the other limit exist so it implies boundedness hence the conclusion is valid

Just like you said, we don't have in general that (xn)  goes to zero then it's product with any sequence goes to zero. A simple counter example is (xn) =(1/n) which goes to zero and (yn) =n. You can easily see that (yn) isn't bounded and their product goes to one not zero.

I hope this help

Comment: You can typeset your answer using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 0):

Without stating it explicitly, you believe that you can use

$$\lim_{x\to0}x\frac{f(x)}x=\lim_{x\to0}x\cdot\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x$$

like is done in the proof.

But you forget an essential ingredient: this holds when the limits exist. In the proof, this is known to be true. But in the general case

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}x$$ may very well fail to be defined.

---

The lesson is: always expand the reasoning with enough details, and check the validity conditions.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to prove may be informally referred to as the *'differentiability implies continuity* theorem, which is exactly what it sounds like (i.e if $f$ is differentiable on an open interval $I'$, then $f$ is continuous on the closed interval $I$ including the endpoints).

Your statement that
\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0}f(x) &= \lim_{x \to 0}x \cdot \frac{f(x)}{x} \\
&= 0
\end{align*}

does not hold since you are assuming that the limit $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)}{x}$ exists in the first place. An example:

Let $f(x) = x \sin(\frac{1}{x})$. Then

\begin{align*}
\lim_{x \to 0} x \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) = \lim_{x \to 0} x \cdot \lim_{x \to 0} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
\end{align*}

for which $\lim_{x \to 0} \sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)$ does not exist.